# Solution for Google Visualization API’s incompatible JSON date format

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I create a dashboard (table, some charts) based on google visualisation api. I feed google api with JSON, but everything works fine until I was try to add DATE format.

Now I have this JSON format:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"ID","type":"number"},{"label":"Masina","type":"string"},{"label":"Model","type":"string"},{"label":"Godina proiz","type":"date"},{"label":"Datum prve reg","type":"date"},{"label":"Reg br","type":"string"},{"label":"Istek reg","type":"date"},{"label":"Snaga","type":"number"},{"label":"Kapacitet","type":"number"},{"label":"Servis","type":"date"},{"label":"Trajna reg","type":"string"},{"label":"Vlasnistvo","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":1},{"v":"traktor"},{"v":"IMT"},{"v":"510-td"},{"v":"\/Date(2014,07,07)\/"},{"v":"\/Date(2014,02,27)\/"},{"v":"BG-657 UI"},{"v":"\/Date(2014,04,24)\/"},{"v":55},{"v":57},{"v":"\/Date(2014,02,18)\/"},{"v":"licno"}]}]}
```

but google say:

```
One or more participants failed to draw()×
```

I was try so many solution but again dont work?

Why google visualisation api dont accept this:

```
{"v":"\/Date(2014,02,27)\/"}
```

Comment: Order of column types and row data doesn't match. 4th column label is `"Godina proiz", "type":"date"},` but as a data there is `{"v":"510-td"},`.

Comment: valid format should be for example `"Date(2010,10,6)"` or `new Date(2008, 1, 28)`